# Probability that a five-card poker hand contains the ace of hearts?

Tags: probability

A standard deck of 52 cards has 13 kinds of cards, with four cards of each kind, one in each of the four suits, hearts, diamonds, spades, and clubs. What is the probability that a five-card poker hand contains the ace of hearts?

Comment: Please elaborate on: 1. What is "poker hand"? 2. What have you tried?

Comment: Hint:  easier to find the probability that it does not contain the given card, and then subtract.

Comment: Hint: If $5$ cards are picked out of $52$ then what is the probability of the ace of hearts to be one of them?

Comment: What ve you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Think of it as if you are the ace of hearts yourself. If $5$ cards are taken, then what is your chance to be one of them?

If you are one of $52$ persons of wich $5$ are elected, all with equal probability. Then what is your chance to be elected?

Answer (score 4):

The probability of the hand NOT containing the ace of hearts is....
 51/52 x 50/51 x 49/50 x 48/49 x 47/48 = 0.9038
So the probability of the hand containing the ace of hearts is 1 - 0.903 = 0.0962

Comment: An additional comment about the advantage of cancelling would improve you answer.

Comment: In my view cancelling is *not* the most effective method here.

Comment: @drhab What do you mean ?

Comment: Simply that there is a better method in this case. See my answer for that.

Comment: @drhab My comment referred to the answer of Malcolm, not to your answer.

Comment: @calculus So did mine. However, you addressed me in your second comment with a question. That made me answer it.